# Как вернуть id при записи в базу при jQuery post - запросе?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Есть html-форма

```
<div class="addnew_block">  
<form id="f_addnew">
<input type="text" name="rnew_title">
<textarea name="rnew_text"></textarea>
<a id="btn_newadd" href="" class="flleft">Отправить</a>
</form>
</div>
```

Js -обработчик:

```
  $(function(){        
    $('.addnew_block').on('click', '#btn_newadd', function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var rnew_title=$(this).siblings("input[name='rnew_title']").val();
        var rnew_text=$(this).siblings("textarea[name='rnew_text']").val();
         event.preventDefault();
    var posting = $.post('/admin/assets/news/news_ajax.php','act=add&'+$('#f_addnew').serialize());
    posting.done(function( data ) {
    if(data){
      ('.addnew_block').append(data.lastId);

        }
        });

    });
});
```

и далее код в файле news_ajax.php:

```
function add(){ 
global $db;
$res=array('res'=>'ошибка в аргументах запроса');
unset($_POST['act']);
if(empty($_POST['rnew_title'])){ echo json_encode($res);exit;}
if(empty($_POST['rnew_text'])){ echo json_encode($res);exit;}
$sql  = "INSERT INTO `mdb_news` SET title=?s,text=?s";
$db->query($sql,$_POST['rnew_title'],$_POST['rnew_text']);
$lastId = $db->insertId();

}
```

Запись нормально в базу добавляется, но не могу вернуть id последней добавленной записи в ответе от сервера. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если следовать приведённому коду, то **news_ajax.php**:

```
function add() { 
 global $db;

 $res = array('res' => 'ошибка в аргументах запроса');

 unset($_POST['act']);

 if(empty($_POST['rnew_title'])) { 
  echo json_encode($res);

  exit;
 }

 if(empty($_POST['rnew_text'])) { 
  echo json_encode($res);

  exit;
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `mdb_news` SET title=?s,text=?s";

 $db->query($sql, $_POST['rnew_title'], $_POST['rnew_text']);

 $lastId = $db->insertId();

 $res = array('lastId' => $lastId);

 echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Comment: Получилось с помощью echo $lastId вернуть, спасибо. И поменяв вот эту строку posting.done(function( data ) {
  if(data){
         alert(data);

   }
   }); получаю этот id в алерте. Как мне на экран вывести, чтобы через append добавлялось к addnew_block?

Comment: @ZaurK, `$('.addnew_block').append(data);`

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось.